# How to convert sharelatex project into PS?

Tags: sharelatex, ps

I have a sharelatex project and i need to covert it into a PS. Even I have downloaded the whole latex project and I tried to install Texmaker. But seems things are not working

Comment: We will need more than ''not working'. First, though, _why_ do you need to convert it to PostScript? What's wrong with PDF?

Comment: Have you also downloaded a TeX distribution? TeXmaker is only the editor, you need a TeX system like TeX Live or MiKTeX to compile your document ...

Comment: ill try , tx...

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to export a project to Postscript in ShareLaTeX.

Source - ShareLaTeX founder